# How to use PostHTTP processor with multiple urls

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use PostHTTP processor with POST method using multiple URLs and trying to send body content also. Dataflow is shown as below in image. Is it possible do it and how? 
Example: PostHTTP-> http://localhost:5000/sum and http://localhost:50001/average ->PublishMQTT
Here, I am using PostHTTP processor to call multiple URLs and then send the response to MQTT and failure to PutFile. I am using GetFile processor at the same time to send the body content to PostHTTP processor but it’s not the correct way because body content file are sent to PutFile from PostHTTP.

Here is the image of the dataflow I have created.

[image]

Comment: `but it’s not the correct way` - why? Please explain what is the problem.

Comment: because I got this error : .PostHTTP PostHTTP[id=88578ffb-016e-1000-ba13-d125606f5439] After substituting attribute values for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=e5de0ec8-7dde-4b2a-85ac-877a74d10a0d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1574240450281-1, container=default, section=1], offset=5933, length=73],offset=0,name=body.json,size=73], URL is ; this is not a valid URL, so routing to failure